# C# - How to add document with REST API in SharePoint 2016 On-Premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, rest, 2016, file

I want to GET documents With **SSOM in SP2007** and upload with **REST to SP2016**

This SSOM code for create doc library: (**Working**):

```
private void CreateList()
{
    var digest = GetFormDigest();

    var url = siteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists";
    var body = "{'__metadata': { type: 'SP.List' }, " +
        "BaseTemplate: 107, " +
        "Title: 'Tasks'}";

    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = creds;
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] =
        "application/json;odata=verbose";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] =
        "application/json;odata=verbose";
    client.Headers["X-RequestDigest"] = digest;
    var json = client.UploadString(url, body);
}
```

**This is my code for add document in SharePoint 2016: (NOT WORKING)**

```
 private static void AddDocumentToNewPortal(byte[] fileArray, string fileName)
{
    var digest = GetFormDigest();

    var url = string.Format(siteURL + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('AQAPs')/Files/Add(url='{0}', overwrite=true)", fileName);
    var body = fileArray.Length.ToString();

    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = creds;
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = fileArray.Length.ToString();
    client.Headers["X-RequestDigest"] = digest;
    var json = client.UploadString(url, body);
}
```

What can I do to add my document code to work?

Comment: Please, double check SP versions - "SharePoint 2017" does not exist. :)

Comment: sorry, sharepont 2016..

Comment: Please help me...

Comment: Since You are working in server side code (C#), could You use "Server Object Model" ?

Comment: CSOM is implemented in SP10, I use Server Object model, because i working with sharepoint 07

Comment: Ok, then.. why can't You execute `SPFile file = lib.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);` for Your SP2016 solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86057/discussion-between-kristaps-vilerts-and-goshky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
//Method to upload File
public static bool AddDocumentToNewPortal(byte[] fileArray, string siteurl, string fileName)
{
    bool status = false;           
    string result = string.Empty;
    //Url to upload file
    string resourceUrl = siteurl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('AQAPs')/Files/add(url='" + fileName + "',overwrite=true)";
    HttpWebRequest wreq = HttpWebRequest.Create(resourceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    wreq.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    //credential who has edit access on document library
    NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
    wreq.Credentials = credentials;

    //Get formdigest value from site
    string formDigest = GetFormDigestValue(siteurl, credentials);
    wreq.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);
    wreq.Method = "POST";
    wreq.Timeout = 1000000; //timeout should be large in order to upload file which are of large size
    wreq.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
    wreq.ContentLength = fileArray.Length;
    try
    {
        using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = wreq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileArray, 0, fileArray.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    try
    {
        WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(wresp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            status = true;
            return status;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return status;
        throw;
    }
}

//Method which return form digest value
private static string GetFormDigestValue(string siteurl, NetworkCredential credentials)
{
    string newFormDigest = "";
    HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteurl + "/_api/contextinfo");
    endpointRequest.Method = "POST";
    endpointRequest.ContentLength = 0;
    endpointRequest.Credentials = credentials;
    endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    try
    {
        WebResponse webResp = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream webStream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
        string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        var j = JObject.Parse(response);
        var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
        foreach (var item in jObj["d"].Children())
        {
            newFormDigest = item.First()["FormDigestValue"].ToString();
        }
        responseReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return newFormDigest;
}
```